# iphone transferring files using iTunes, but not allowing user to see all of docs directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, documents

It doesn't sound like this is possible, but I will ask anyway.

In my app, I store a lot of images and plists in the documents directory.

I would like to implement a PDF reader in the app that allows users to load their PDFs into the app via iTunes. I do not want the user to be able to see/access the contents of the documents directory since they could cause the app to perform unexpectedly if they messed with these files.

Is this possible, or is it possible to place my plists and images somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be registered with Apple to see this, but [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10) should give you the information you need.

You'll need to add a `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to `Info.plist`. This will give the user access to the Documents directory of the app, and let them remove or add files.

[This tutorial](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/06/14/ipad-sdk-3-2-document-support-1/) gives an example of how to set up PDF support in an iPad app.

Comment: My main question was where to put my files that I didnt want them to see, which I found the answer on that first link, the Library folder, which is not something I have used before. Thanks.